# First chance exception at 0x5919c8ec (msvcr100d.dll): 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xfeeefeee

Tags: c++

I'm having this error while comparing two strings (using an overloaded operator).

The error happens here :

```
void addEtu(node *Node, element *Etu){
    if (Node->Value == NULL)
        Node->Value = Etu;
    else{
        if (Node->left == NULL && *Node > *Etu) //This line specifically
            Node->left->Value = Etu;
        else if (Node->left != NULL && *Node->left < *Node)
            addEtu(Node->left, Etu);
        else if (Node->right == NULL)
            Node->right->Value = Etu;
        else
            addEtu(Node->right, Etu);
    }
}
```

And redirects to iosfwd; to this function specifically :

```
static int __CLRCALL_OR_CDECL compare(const _Elem *_First1, const _Elem *_First2,
        size_t _Count)
        {   // compare [_First1, _First1 + _Count) with [_First2, ...)
        return (_CSTD memcmp(_First1, _First2, _Count));
        }
```

node is a structure containing two more nodes and 'value', a structure containing a some strings.
The overload is as follow :

```
bool operator>(const node& V1, const node& V2){
    if (V1.Value->Code > V2.Value->Code)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

The node taken into parameter by the function addEtu is the root (of a binary tree), it's initialized as follow :

```
void Initialize(node *Root){
    Root->right = NULL;
    Root->left = NULL;
    Root->Value = NULL;
}
```

The error happens the second time addEtu is called.

I've no idea what's wrong, I Googled for about an hour and found nothing relevant to my specific error, as any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are storing `Etu` in the tree, but after you exit `addEtu`, you are deleting `Etu`.  This means the node in the tree is now pointing to a deleted object.

Comment: Hm, I think that's the problem. But I'm not sure how to manage that. If I don't delete it, every time I call the function again it will overwrite it, will it not?

Comment: Nevermind, just commenting the delete etu did it. Thanks a lot, I've been looking all day to fix this.

Answer (score 3):

[0xFEEEFEEE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29#Magic_debug_values) is a pattern used by VS to mark freed pointers on debug builds. So you have a dangling pointer (namely a pointer you've already freed), which you're trying to dereference. Given `Node->left` doesn't throw, it's probably `Etu`.

Comment: `Etu` is created in a case (in a switch), which is filled with information from the user. I then call `addEtu` taking `Etu` in parameter. After this, I delete `Etu`. The case in which `Etu` is created may be called again. Would this be the problem?

Comment: You're probably trying to add an Etu after you delete it, by having the following (pseudo-code) sequence: `Etu = new element; addEtu(Etu); delete Etu; addEtu(Etu);`.

Comment: I don't think so, the case goes like this : `case 1: element *Etu = new element; addEtu(Etu); delete Etu; break;` `delete Etu;` and `break;` are at the very end of the case.

Comment: Well, from what I can tell Etu's value is 0xFEEEFEEE instead of a real `element`. You should be able to see that in the debugger. If it's indeed so, you're skipping some `Etu = new element` (missing `break` in the case maybe?). I don't have the rest of the code so I can't say exactly what's happening, but there might be a difference between what you think is happening and what is actually happening. Note that the error is on the *second* call to `addEtu`, which you don't describe in the comment above.

Comment: Well I'm pretty sure I'm not skipping a new element nor a break. If you want to check by yourself, I uploaded the code (translated it roughly) to pastebin : http://pastebin.com/imPVTiQu